# you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead. in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating an application on ruby on rails:

After creating users, for validating users I am running below commands:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
$ bundle exec rake test:prepare
```

Both command are run properly on the rails commandLine, but when I run the below command:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
```

I am getting error below:

```
Warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead.
Warning: or add 'gem "minitest"' before 'require "minitest/autorun"'
```

And I am using `4.1.1` version of `rails`.
I don't understand why it comes.
Kindly suggest me, waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Comment: if you're not using minitest, remove it from your app.

Comment: but i am using it, kindly suggest me, what should I do?

Comment: then why are you trying to run rspec commands? it's not typical to use both, they do the same job (testing).

Comment: kindly elaborate for me I am new.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Include minitest gem in your 'Gemfile' and run bundle install

```
gem install 'minitest'
```

and then `bundle install`

Comment: This answer solution like it was a workaround? The questioner, op, is asking to run a testing framework rspec - adding another testing framework, minitest, might solve the warning but could introduce conflicts in the future - Rspec users will want to follow Chris Nelson's cleaner solution.

Comment: It absolutely does not work for me. Minitest is installed and still have the problem, for any "rake" command.
I'm using rake 10.4, rails 4.2.3 and ruby 2.1.5

Comment: @AlexPierstoval Did you run bundle exec rake db:migrate and bundle exec rake test:prepare after modifying to Gemfile, request you to please restart the server and check once again or let me know if problem still there, would be great if u can give the exact error message.

Comment: I ran everything, minitest was installed automatically by the "bundle install" command.
I don't know where the problem could be found, but actually, I removed every gem, reinstalled bundler, removed the "Gemfile.lock" file, ran "bundle install" again, and after that only it worked...
Sorry for annoyance.

Answer (score 13):

More a note for posterity than anything, but this issue can also happen if you're using an older version of shoulda-matchers. You can see some discussion around this on their Github repo [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/308), or on the rspec-rails repo [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/758).

Update shoulda-matchers by running `bundle update shoulda-matchers`. You want the latest version (or at least 2.6.2) and this message should go away.

Comment: This is a better solution unless you happen to be using (and requiring) `minitest` directly in your app.

Comment: Very true. This fix only applies if you're using shoulda-matchers but not `minitest`.

Comment: Updating the shoulda-matchers to the latest version solved the problem. Thanks!